# Why serializing an ImageList doesn't work well

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm using a `BinaryFormatter`, I serialize a treeview .
Now I want to do the same thing for an `ImageList`

I used this code to serialize :

```
    public static void SerializeImageList(ImageList imglist)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("imagelist.iml", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, imglist.ImageStream);
        fs.Close();

    }
```

and this one to deserialize :

```
    public static void DeSerializeImageList(ref ImageList imgList)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("imagelist.iml", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        imgList.ImageStream = (ImageListStreamer)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

    }
```

but I get an empty string in all keys !!

```
ImgList.Images.Keys
```

why ?

Comment: It is because ImageListStreamer only serializes ImageList data, it is not a substitute to serialize a complete ImageList.  You are using it in a way it was not intended to be used, it is a helper class to get ImageList data serialized into a .resx file.  The designer uses it.

Comment: @HansPassant the ImageList that I use can be changed in run time , I use its keys in TreeView to display images(after appending it),where do you recommend to save it? to save it in .resx file ? if so , how ? or for example to save the keys in text file and to fill the ImageList keys in form load ?

Answer (score 0):

Most humans do not use their full resources to cross reference what they already know. `ImageList` is not serializable in its current form, but there are only two things you really want to save in it and that is the `Key` and the `Image`. So you build an intermediate class to hold them, that is serializable, as in the following example:

```
[Serializable()]
public class FlatImage
{
    public Image _image { get; set; }
    public string _key { get; set; }
}

void Serialize()
{
    string path = Options.GetLocalPath("ImageList.bin");
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    List<FlatImage> fis = new List<FlatImage>();
    for (int index = 0; index < _smallImageList.Images.Count; index++)
    {
        FlatImage fi = new FlatImage();
        fi._key = _smallImageList.Images.Keys[index];
        fi._image = _smallImageList.Images[index];
        fis.Add(fi);
    }

    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, fis);
    }
}

void Deserialize()
{
    string path = Options.GetLocalPath("ImageList.bin");
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            List<FlatImage> ilc = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<FlatImage>;

            for( int index = 0; index < ilc.Count; index++ )
            {
                Image i = ilc[index]._image;
                string key = ilc[index]._key;
                _smallImageList.Images.Add(key as string, i);
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```