# How to speed up adding images to ImageList?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

So I'm trying to populate a large amount of icons to a listview.  In order to avoid long wait times, I'm trying to get it to load the first 1000 results and then load more if the user presses a load more button.

Here's where I'm stuck.  If I load all 10,000+ icons at once it takes me 37 sec.  However, if I decide to add 500 more icons everytime the user clicks the button it takes me 40 sec which is worse than adding it all at once!  The only difference in code is that I had to make this one line a delegate to avoid cross-threading issues.  Is there a faster way to do this?

```
for (int i = lastLoadedIndex; i < lastLoadedIndex+500; i++)
{
    string file = resultArr[i];

    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes sense in your application, but maybe you can use more than one ImageList? Maybe one for staters and another one to fill up the rest while the user is still looking through the first batch.. Ot prtition the 1ok into 10 ImageLists..

Comment: @JLYK put `Image.FromFile(file)` outside the `Invoke` block. Putting it inside the invoke block causes it to run on the GUI thread.

Comment: Same kind of problem as String vs StringBuilder.  It is very important to use its Items.AddRange() method.  So it doesn't constantly have to re-allocate its internal storage.

Answer (score 3):

To speed up any *bulk* operation, consider using the *bulk* method if it is available.
For instance, the `ImageCollection` type has the `AddRange` method.
Try to use it:

```
int newCount = 500;

// Get a desired part of the `resultArr` array as a new array:
string[] tmp = new string[newCount];
Array.Copy(resultArr, lastLoadedIndex, tmp, 0, newCount);

// Load images:
Image[] images = Array.ConvertAll(tmp, file => Image.FromFile(file));

// Bulk add images to the ImageList:
Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => imageList1.Images.AddRange(images)));
```

If won't help, please check which operation is slow: reading of images or appending to the `ImageList`.

Comment: AddRange can't seem to handle more than 9000+ images but it works great if I keep the numbers lower than that.

Comment: @JLYK Then try to split your big `ImageList` into several small ones. Additionally, if you need the same set of images each time, you could try to serialize the `ImageList` once, and  deserialize it as many times as you need.

Comment: I've [found out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084544/why-serializing-an-imagelist-doesnt-work-well) that it's easy to serialize an `ImageList` via its `ImageStream` property, but it's very hard to deserialize it. So the splitting is the only option I can suggest.

Comment: So splitting the big ImageList seems to be working for me so far.  But after every update, I lose my place in the listview and I end up selecting an icon that wasn't what I wanted to click on in the first place.  Any idea how to make the ImageList update more seamlessly?

Comment: In my tests, ImageList.AddRange was not faster than a loop with .Add. They have pretty much the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT #2: The expensive part of the function is loading the image from the file. Placing it before locking the mutex should allow for some parallelism worth the overhead of using the mutex. No, this method does not preserve order.
EDIT: Add images directly to image list rather than to a temporary collection.

```
public void LoadImagesFromFiles(string[] files)
{
    Mutex imageListLock = new Mutex();
    files.AsParallel().ForAll(file =>
    {
        var img = Image.FromFile(file);
        imageListLock.WaitOne();
        this.imageList1.Images.Add(img);
        imageListLock.ReleaseMutex();
    });
}
```

Comment: This loads Images. I'm afraid it'll bear heavy on the GDI resources, as opposed to an ImageList, which doesn't do that.

Comment: So using files.AsParallel() has definitely helped improve speed.  Loading all results take 27sec now.  However when I used Mutex the speed went back up to 37sec.  Also, is there a way to preserve the order that the images get added?

Comment: This is a common mistake when using multithreading. In this case the first thing that happens in the body of the loop is locking the mutex. Besides the fact that this is pretty much the same as a sequential loop, in this case there's also the overhead of locking on a mutex object, so this could _potentially_ be even slower than a regular for loop.